# Importing Participants

Tags: civievent, import

I am trying to import multiple participants from a CSV file into Civi as event participants. I am running into an issue when I go to match the required fields. I keep receiving an error because the Participant Status ID doesn't match.

This is a historic event I am trying to enter from another database, so I don't believe we have a match for this field. Is there a way to get around this?

Most of the constituents are already in Civi and have an external identifier from the past database. I now just to update their record to note that they attended the event.

Comment: do you have a column for participants status name(registered, attended, canceled etc), change it to the status id, civicrm/admin/participant_status?reset=1, if you don't have that column add it and indicate the status with the id

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried that strategy and it still gave me the same error notification. Any other ideas?

Comment: can you test with dummy data on the demo site? the participant status id should be something like 2 for attended or match your participant status

Answer (score 2):

"Participant Status ID doesn't match" means the value(s) you are trying to insert into this field do not match the option values defined in CiviCRM.

Both **Particpant status** and **Participant status Id** are in the list of possible fields to import. Although the UI indicates that you need to import **Participant status Id**  I think you can import **participant status** instead provide the text you import matches exactly with the defined options.

You could be tring to import values such as 'Registered' or 'Attended' into **Participant status Id** when it is expecting numerical values  or you could be trying to import a text value into **Participant status** that is not one of the defined options. (perhaps 'Att' or 'attended' instead of 'Attended')

Comment: I like this answer - Allison: did you work it out?

Answer (score 1):

Is your CSV file actually **comma-delimited**?

If you choose another delimiter (e.g. semicolon or tab), the import might not work. Been stuck with this issue for hours before figuring out that might actually be a bug in CiviCRM.

See: [Can't import Event participants](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14263/cant-import-event-participants)

Answer (score 0):

If the file you uploaded did not use commas as the file delimiter, then it's likely you were seeing [CRM-19192: Event participants (and possibly other entity) imports do not handle "non-comma CSV"](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19192).