# Can't import Event participants

Tags: wordpress, import

I can't figure out how to import event participants.
I have created an event (ID=1).
Same problem with event ID=3.

No matter whether I use Participant status or Participant status ID, CiviCRM gives me error for all lines.

*Missing required field(s) :Event Participant Status.*

What data should I be providing to CiviCRM to make it work?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PROBLEM SOLVED!**

It turns out that **semicolon** does not work as *Import Field Separator*.
With **comma** every went as it was supposed.

P.S. Microsoft Excel saves CSV files semicolon-separated.

Comment: Sounds like the Excel on that PC might be configured to do something non-standard there, since [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) stands for "comma-separated values". Glad you found it!  I've been there :) There is actually a note below import page's file upload box stating that CSVs must be comma-separated.

Comment: ... and then the form [asks for the field separator](http://i.imgur.com/PG935gr.png), so I'm left as confused as you are :D FWIW I tried this semicolon separated file: `John;Doe;098118111`, it worked importing a contact:

Comment: @ChrisBurgess Indeed, **CSV** literally stands for *comma-separated values*, but it is just a name of file type. In reality there are many formats and many other delimiters are used in this format. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

CiviCRM explicitly offers to use different delimiters.

Maybe semicolon works for importing contact or contact with simple data. Try semicolon when importing event participants. Or **tab** delimiter when importing contact data (or a bit more complicated contact data).

Comment: Yep, I concur: this is reproducible. I've reported a bug at [CRM-19192: Contributions (and possibly other entity) imports do not handle "non-comma CSV"](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19192). For now, I'd recommend just using comma-separated CSV. Identifying a bug like this is a good contribution, so thanks for taking the time to ask your question today!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I set my import up and use it every week and it works.

[image: Event participant import]

This is how my csv is setup.

[image: CSV file]

Answer (score 1):

Along with the *CiviCRM has detected invalid data or formatting errors in 50 records* message you should have an option to download a CSV of the records which had errors. If you open this CSV, you should see the particular records and field(s) that didn't make sense to CiviCRM.

The easiest way to get the "expected" (=valid) values for import is to add a single record with values like you want to see, and then export it from CiviCRM.

Comment: Whatever I try to do, it returns error. I added record manually, then created a CSV in the same way, error again.

Since I am trying to import 50 lines, I see all my lines in those 50 records. See screenshot in this thread on what I am importing.

*I have verified Contact IDs, Participant Role IDs, Participant Status IDs. All are valid, enabled, etc. Am I missing something obvious?*

I tried different ways. With "Participant Status" and with "Participant Status ID", "Role" and "Role ID", Event ID and Event Title, and so on...

Comment: No matter what I try, I get the same error in downloaded CSV:
*Missing required field(s) :Event Participant Status.*

**How do I indicate Event participant status?** I guess by using Participant Status ID (numerical: 1, 2, etc.) or by using Participant Status (text: Registered, Attended, etc.) Unfortunately neither works.